# Repeat click in UIWebView?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a website with a big transparent advertisement layer. So if an user clicks on a page this layer catches this click, becomes hidden and creates (or even goes to) a page with another advertisement. The websites' functionality involves html and javascript.

Of course I could use method `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType` and return no if the user clicks on an link I don't like. But the problem is he should repeat his click again to achieve a goal. Instead of it I could repeat the first click twice. Is it possible? Or are there better solutions?

Comment: you want the first click to register as two clicks ?

Comment: Yes. Maybe with delay between them

Comment: why not just remove the layer when page is loaded?

Comment: ok, how to do it using objective-c/javascript?